# Google Docs: What is the conversion from points to pixels?

Tags: fonts, google-apps-script, styles, pixel

In the Google Apps Script documentation, it vaguely refers to points multiple times, for instance [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body), to refer to dimensions of the page. A quick Google search turned up that this conversion depends on many factors, including font size. So what does this number really mean, and can I convert it to pixels in the code?

Here is a sample from the link above:

**getPageHeight()**

Retrieves the page height, in points.

Returns:

Number — the page height, in points

**getPageWidth()**

Retrieves the page width, in points.

Returns:

Number — the page width, in points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Points are traditionally used in print media (anything that is to be printed on paper, etc.). One point is equal to 1/72 of an inch. Points are much like pixels, in that they are fixed-size units and cannot scale in size.